# "Select NOT IN" clause in Linq to Entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

Is there a way to use the "NOT IN (select XXX...)" clause in Linq to Entities?
All the questions I found were regarding a list of objects (IN (1,2,3)) but I want to generate a query with the following syntax:

```
select * from table1 where field1 not in (select subfield from subtable)
```

Be aware that this is Linq to Entities and not Linq to Sql...

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like this:

```
from c in db.Customers
where !db.Products.Any(p => p.ProductID == c.ProductID)
select c;
```

Comment: Finally ! An answer that works great, even without EF4 ! Thanks !

Comment: @SLaks: What will be the equivalent in Method syntax?

Comment: @FMFF: `db.Customers.Where(c => !db.Products.Any(...))`